# Trying to join two queries and retrieve a column

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two queries

Query 1:

```
select ProposalTypeID 
from tblAssessment 
where AssessmentID = AssessmentID
```

Query 2:

```
select AssessmentID 
from tblAssessmentVersion 
where AssessmentVersionID = 3
```

Thanks for the guidance but I was trying to add that query in stored procedure to retrieve `proposalTypeID` and use in my stored procedure but it complains

```
SELECT 
    AssessmentEcosystemCreditID, AssessmentVersionID, 
    dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.ManagementZoneID, 
    (SELECT ProposalTypeID 
     FROM tblAssessment 
     WHERE AssessmentID = (SELECT AssessmentID  
                           FROM tblAssessmentVersion 
                           WHERE AssessmentVersionID = dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentVersionID)) AS ProposalTypeID,
    CASE 
       WHEN SiteValueCurrentScore <= 17 AND (dbo.tblVegetationZone.EECID > 0 ) AND (ProposalTypeID=699) 
          THEN 0
          ELSE NumberOfCredits
    END AS NumberOfCreditst
FROM 
    dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblVegetationType ON dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblManagementZone ON dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.ManagementZoneID = dbo.tblManagementZone.ManagementZoneID 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone ON dbo.tblVegetationZone.VegetationZoneID = dbo.tblManagementZone.VegetationZoneID
WHERE 
    dbo.tblAssessmentEcosystemCredit.AssessmentVersionID = @AssessmentVersionID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so?

```
select ProposalTypeID 
from tblAssessment 
where AssessmentID in 
  (select AssessmentID 
   from tblAssessmentVersion 
   where AssessmentVersionID=3)
```

Comment: Would be safer to use "IS IN"

Answer (score 1):

```
select ProposalTypeID 
from tblAssessment 
where AssessmentID = (select AssessmentID 
                      from tblAssessmentVersion 
                      where AssessmentVersionID = 3)
```